# opening excel or text file - options for comma delimited not showing up

Tags: excel

I am trying to open a .dat file in excel or sigma plot. First, the file kept downloading as a PDF automatically. Then I changed the file extension to excel and also tried txt. When I try to open it from right clicking, choosing open with and then choosing excel, it doesn't give me the option to open the file as comma delimited. The data is all squished into one column with the commas still there.

How to I get my windows computer to allow me to open the file with commas delimiting so I can separate the data into cells?

Answer (score 0):

Open up an instance of Excel first, then open the file from there.  This should give you the dialogue to open with comma delimiting.  Be sure to select "All Files" when opening the file so that .txt files are visible.